# Using PrimeNG with the DllBundlesPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, primeng

I'd like to use some components of PrimeNG but encountering some errors when trying to include it via the DllBundlesPlugin.

The `DllBundlesPlugin` configuration:

```
new DllBundlesPlugin({
      bundles: {
        polyfills: [
          'core-js',
          'zone.js'
        ],
        vendor: [
          '@angular/platform-browser',
          '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
          '@angular/core',
          '@angular/common',
          '@angular/forms',
          '@angular/http',
          '@angular/router',
          '@angularclass/hmr',
          'rxjs',
       '@ngui/auto-complete',
      'ngx-bootstrap',
      '@swimlane/ngx-datatable',
      'primeng/primeng'
    ]
  },
  dllDir: './web/dist/vendor/',
  webpackConfig: {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    plugins: [] // DllBundlesPlugin will set the DllPlugin here
  }
})
```

The error:

> Error: Package name mismatch, Expected primeng/primeng but found primeng

Using `primeng` instead of `primeng/primeng` results in `Cannot find module 'primeng'`.

If there's no simple fix, is there another way of using PrimeNG (without the plugin)?

Comment: Did you try valery-vitko's answer to [your question on github](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/webpack-dll-bundles-plugin/issues/16)? He suggested to add the name in addition to the path. You would replace `'primeng/primeng'` by `{ name: 'primeng', path: 'primeng/primeng' }` in the `vendor` list.